# Real Analysis basic questions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am studying for math 400 lvl class and I forgot how one to one function on infinity value. For instance, consider the following:

$$f(x)=tx+g, \hspace{1cm} -\infty < x < + \infty, \quad t,g, \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Question: is is it one to one? I think it is not one to one function because it fails horizontal line test when it's graphed.

Please correct me if i am wrong. Any help would be appreciated it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First you need to remind yourself what is the condition for the function be one-to-one, and that is

$$f(x) = f(y) \text{ implies } x=y, \text{ for all } x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Let's figure if this is true for the given function. Assuming $f(x) = f(y)$ we have

$$tx+g = ty+g, \text{ therefore } tx=ty.$$

If $t = 0$ then it is not one-to-one, as for any values of $x,y$ we have $0 \cdot x = 0 \cdot y$.

If $t \neq 0$, on the other hand, we can divide by it, obtaining $x=y$, hence an one-to-one function.

Comment: Thank you very much. i deeply appreciate your help.